# Посчитать количество записей в связи - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть сервис вопросов и ответов и есть две таблицы:

questions с полем id answers с полем id и id_question

Как мне посчитать в списке вопросов количество ответов на эти вопросы? Допустим идет вопрос и в скобках сколько на него ответов

Например вот так нужно (см фото)
http://www.cyberforum.ru/attachments/952186d1531056586

Сейчас запрос у меня выглядит так:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY date DESC limit 20";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo '
<div>'.$r['title'].'</div>
<div>Ответов: </div>                               
';
}
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $id=$r['id'];        
    $answers = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE id_question='$id'"));
```

Comment: Вставляю это после while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   в коде вставляю переменную $answers и ничего не показывает в месте вывода количества ответов.

Comment: Попробуйте цикл do while вместо while

Comment: ЗАРАБОТАЛО) спасибо! Перепутал перменную